# Cell of GridView with Currency

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, uwp

Bello everybody! I have a question. 
I have a project with SQLite, in UWP app. Web I put the list of db into the GridView, how  can I write in the field a number with the currency format (i.e. 5,40€)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind the currency field in db to a control in the GridView (**assuming a TextBlock**), you can use the Converter method in Binding to convert currency format.

When you convert currency format, you can add the "C" qualifier to the format parameter of the **ToString()** method and if you want to display an amount with "€", you can set the xx parameter of ToString to point to the required culture.

Below I simply use TextBlock as an example.

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:ScenarioBindingConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyName" Text="{x:Bind MyPrice,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

.vb:

```
Namespace Global.AppVB
    Partial Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
        Inherits Page

        Public MyPrice As String

        Public Sub New()
            Me.InitializeComponent()
            MyPrice = "4.5889"

        End Sub
    End Class


    Public Class ScenarioBindingConverter
        Implements IValueConverter
        Private _DecimalValue As Decimal

        Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
            _DecimalValue = 0D
            If value.ToString() > 0 Then
                If Not Decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, _DecimalValue) Then

                Else
                    Return _DecimalValue.ToString("c", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"))
                End If
            End If
        End Function

        Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```